# Pyspark replace for loop over dates

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aggregate, transform

I have an array of dates:

```
date_set = ["2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01"....."2020-01-01"]
```

and I have this dataframe:

```
|DATE     |ID             |VALUE|
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+
|  2019-04|       1234    |100.0|
|  2019-05|       4567    |200.0|
```

For each element of my list, I have to apply the following transformations:

```
for date in date_set:
   target = date - relativedelta(months=+6)
   dfTemp = df.where(
       (F.col("DATE") <= date) &
       (F.col("DATE") >= target)
   ).groupBy("ID").agg(F.sum("VALUE").alias("VALUE"))
```

I want to avoid this for loop. How can I do it in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Make a dataframe of your date list, cross join it to your dataframe, and then use window functions to get the rolling sum over the past 6 months:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.show()
+-------+----+-----+
|   DATE|  ID|VALUE|
+-------+----+-----+
|2019-04|1234|100.0|
|2019-05|4567|200.0|
+-------+----+-----+


date_set = ["2019-%02d-01" % i for i in range(1,13)] + ["2020-01-01"]
dates = spark.createDataFrame([[i] for i in date_set]).toDF('date')
dates_id = dates.crossJoin(df2.select('ID').distinct())

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'date',
    F.to_date('DATE', 'yyyy-MM')
).join(
    dates_id,
    ['date', 'ID'],
    'right'
).withColumn(
    'deltamonth',
    F.month('date') - F.min(F.month('date')).over(Window.partitionBy('id'))
).withColumn(
    'sum_value',
    F.sum('value').over( 
        Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('deltamonth').rangeBetween(-6,0)
    )
).drop('deltamonth').orderBy('date', 'ID')
```

Results:

```
df2.show(50)
+----------+----+-----+---------+
|      date|  ID|VALUE|sum_value|
+----------+----+-----+---------+
|2019-01-01|1234| null|     null|
|2019-01-01|4567| null|     null|
|2019-02-01|1234| null|     null|
|2019-02-01|4567| null|     null|
|2019-03-01|1234| null|     null|
|2019-03-01|4567| null|     null|
|2019-04-01|1234|100.0|    100.0|
|2019-04-01|4567| null|     null|
|2019-05-01|1234| null|    100.0|
|2019-05-01|4567|200.0|    200.0|
|2019-06-01|1234| null|    100.0|
|2019-06-01|4567| null|    200.0|
|2019-07-01|1234| null|    100.0|
|2019-07-01|4567| null|    200.0|
|2019-08-01|1234| null|    100.0|
|2019-08-01|4567| null|    200.0|
|2019-09-01|1234| null|    100.0|
|2019-09-01|4567| null|    200.0|
|2019-10-01|1234| null|    100.0|
|2019-10-01|4567| null|    200.0|
|2019-11-01|1234| null|     null|
|2019-11-01|4567| null|    200.0|
|2019-12-01|1234| null|     null|
|2019-12-01|4567| null|     null|
|2020-01-01|1234| null|     null|
|2020-01-01|4567| null|     null|
+----------+----+-----+---------+
```